# SQL and NoSql at the same time?

Tags: sql, nosql, social-networking

my problem : write a social app that has got a wall pages.

i am considering using **sql and nosql at the same time**.
CRUD operations to nosqlrepository and sqlrepository at the same time.

- When to use   sql >>  when querying.
- When to use nosql >>  when getting aggregate objects.

Such as on sql db I have member,wall,wall_like tables,i use it when i need to query the wall.

on the other hand on nosql db i have wall document for every user that consists of all wall items and wall_likes aggregated for faster loading and scalability.

Any body got an experience for this kind of polygot database usage ?

What should i look for when building this kind of architecture ?

What kind of transaction system should i use in dot net for this kind of architecture ?

What kind of model in my classes should i construct ? different for each db or the same but use transient attributes?

*** real life experience is appreciated

Comment: Looks like you got a lot of questions on this topic. You may want to break this question apart into smaller specific questions (or post this job to rent-acoder.com)

Comment: smaller questions does not reflect the main picture.

Comment: **There is no such thing as NoSQL**. There is a whole bunch of new database technologies with completely different design philosophies and use-cases, and all they have in common are things they also have in common with SQL databases. You can't evaluate "NoSQL" as a whole. You need to evaluate each of these technologies separately.

Answer (score 0):

some comments:

Choosing which data goes in which db, you base your decision on pros and cons for each of SQL/NoSQL.`NoSQL` doesn't observe ACID. Data that doesn't need ACID goes to NoSQL, the opposite goes to the RDBMS. Ex. an App tracking millions of customers clicks, and then performing intensive calculations towards a report. It is not mandatory to fetch all the clicks, some misses are allowed. So you can be satisfied with `BASE` vs `ACID`. For tracking payments, you need `ACID`.

Comment: thats why i consider using them at the same time.I am looking for some one who has done it to share their experience...

Comment: Note: While it may not have been available in April 28, there are now Databases that Support both SQL and NoSQL with ACID Transaction support for the noSQL. Informix http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/informix/ and Voltdb http://www.voltdb.com